Are common mode chokes really needed for Conducted Emission standards when there are only two terminals?
Common mode chokes make sense for power inputs when there are three terminals: power line, power return line and an "earth ground". You measure the noise of power line with reference to earth ground (or power return line with reference to earth ground), and a common mode choke along with Y capacitors filter the common mode noise nicely. However, imagine you are designing an automotive circuit and you are powered by car battery remotely. Your power return is connected to battery negative terminal, and the measurement device also measures noise with reference to battery negative terminal. Isn't this basically measuring differential noise? If so, is there really a need for common mode chokes for power lines with only two terminals? I would rather use a single inductor or a ferrite bead.
I know that there is also chassis and cable shield as a reference. However, if chassis was metallic (then it is probably connected to cable shield), wouldn't it be also connected to battery negative terminal?
For those uninitiated, there are Conducted Emission standards for automotive, military etc. grade circuits, where common mode noise is measured with a circuit called LISN (line impedance stabilization network), which is sometimes also called AN (artificial network). Here is a datasheet/application note of a LISN. In Figure 1, you can see the what's inside the LISN (what is important is measurement device will be connected to J4, whose reference is connected to P2 and P4 terminals. In Figure 10, you can see the connections I mentioned.

I'm not sure about the exact technical definition, but in general terms differential noise would simply be noise on more than one signal but in different directions (voltage-wise), and common mode noise would be noise on multiple signals but in the same direction (voltage-wise).
Both are applicable where you have a bunch of related signals wired together, so by no means just applicable in the context of AC mains supplies. For example it is custom to use common mode choke filters on differential signal pairs like CAN or RS485.

In a mains network, the N is grounded in the transformer (assuming Y connection) and the wire is run from the transformer to the consumer. The consumer may also get a separate ground (PE - protective earth) wire (TN-S) or they may have their own ground connection locally (TT). Either case, N and PE will not be at the same potential. So if the equipment has, for example, earthed chassis then we can talk about common mode noise (across L-PE and N-PE) along with differential mode noise (across L-N).

In automotive, the vehicle's metal chassis is connected to the battery negative. I'm not sure if it's used for carrying return currents but this massive body is used as a reference, may also be used for carrying the fault currents though.
If your equipment has a metal enclosure and it's connected to the chassis then there's a possibility of having common mode noise due to the relatively long, and potentially high-current-carrier wires:

One may think that the potential difference between the equipment's supply negative terminal and the chassis can generally be too low to ignore. But in a longer vehicle such as a double-decker in which the battery is generally located at the far back of the vehicle, the cabling might be long. Plus, depending on the placement, the equipment may get its supply wire connections from a closer junction so, since there are going to be multiple devices that draw current and "pollute" the rails, the possibility of having a nonnegligible potential difference between the negative terminal and the chassis increases.

The way I am seeing it now is a common mode choke will not help you pass Conducted Emission tests when your power lines are not isolated from battery, but it can be useful for real life scenarios.

The chassis will be grounded but one cannot let large currents pass through it both for electrical safety and metal durability reasons. So grounds for stuff like motors, starters, valves etc should not go through chassis. Ideally large currents only pass through -, meaning there's a significant potential difference between - and chassis when that happens, though some portion of it might reflect back into the chassis. In addition, the chassis is most often painted steel and not an ideal conductor compared to tin/copper wires and connectors.

@aaroniero Not sure why you are so focused on conducted emissions, specifically? That's usually the easiest part to pass. A common mode choke will likely help a lot with conducted susceptibility testing.

@Lundin - Not sure of OP's configuration, but common mode currents of as little as 15 uA on an unshielded cable can cause you to fail RE (radiated emissions) tests.

@SteveSh Yeah that's what I'm saying, CE testing is usually the least concern. RE testing against MIL standards means >24dBuV/m = fail. Some MIL standards are tougher yet.

There aren't just two lines!  There are connected cables, on most devices.  A common-mode disturbance where e.g. both (DC+/-) terminals of a power supply, are pushed around with respect to the mains (H/N), closes the loop in the common mode, allowing noise to be pushed up the mains supply (and down the attached equipment!).
It helps to realize that, at high frequencies, mains H/N are shorted together by the X capacitor, and DC+/- by the output capacitor.  A power supply unit therefore acts as a one-port: two terminals, joined by the impedance of the isolation barrier and CMCs.  A similar analysis applies to other kinds of equipment, where a whole connector/cable might be considered as a conductor for CM purposes.
Automotive is typically different, as the chassis is frequently used for grounding, and attached devices likely do the same.  There is no current balancing in that case, for inputs or outputs, and only differential mode (or "normal mode" if you like) is applicable.  This is worse, in one way: the unbalanced DC causes inductors to saturate, and they must be rated not just for current flow but magnetization as well.  This rules out ferrite beads, except for signal lines, and perhaps very large beads or when it doesn't much matter that the added impedance varies widely with bias.  Basically, use an "inductor" instead -- it's rated for both Irms and Isat.  Introduce losses if necessary, say by paralleling L with R, or using R+Cs.
When units do have return wires (say, insulated/potted modules on wiring harnesses, or installed in fiberglass bodies), CMCs will be needed as in the mains case.  Or for modules with isolated connections, same idea, no shared ground.  The upside to metal chassis is, you have a common ground plane pretty much everywhere, which makes filtering easy: impedances can be low, and grounding frequent.  Between wiring harnesses, there isn't much grounding available, and what there is, is attached to long exposed antennas, with fairly high impedance (the CM impedance of a cable/harness will generally be in the 100-200Ω range, with peaks above/below this mean due to various resonances), so the CMCs tend to need high impedances as well (low kΩ say).

Thank you. You said unbalanced DC causes inductors to saturate and this rules out ferrite beads. More specifically, did you mean that ferrite beads cannot handle voltage transients and their inductance drop more than a similar inductor for a certain peak current? If so, why is this related to unbalanced DC, as voltage transients can also occur for balanced DC systems?

CMCs are also known as "current compensated chokes". The equal and opposite magnetization of two windings (or three for the 3ph case) cancel out, and a high permeability core can be used (read: that saturates from little (total) magnetization, perhaps a few ampere-turns). You can't do this with an unbalanced circuit, there's no equal and opposite wire to pair with it. Voltage transients don't matter per se, but $\int v dt$ = flux also matters (which is true for any application, balanced or not).

Put another way: DC current biases the core towards saturation, reducing (or eliminating) flux available to consume incident AC. A saturated core has a low impedance and thus little effect on incident AC, so saturation should be avoided for filter inductors.
